# Need help- basic Java code.(Fibonacci Series)

Tags: java, fibonacci

Very new Java programmer and I'm trying to get myself around this Fibonacci problem. (Leaving out the import/class defines

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Put in how many you want to input");
    numToPrint = sc.nextInt();
    sc.close();

    int current = 1;
    int last = 0;
    System.out.println(last);
    System.out.println(current);

    // This is the section I don't really understand.
    int lastlast;
    for (int c =2; c < numToPrint; c++){
        lastlast = last; //How does last variable change from 0 as assigned from above?
        last = current; // How does current variable change from 1? 
        current = lastlast + last;
        System.out.println(current);
        }
      }
```

Comment: I don't understand your question but I think you have a little issue: `a = b` means that you're assigning value `b` to var `a` and not the other way around.

Comment: I suggest you step through the code in your debugger and you will be able see what each line does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the OP is a very new Java Programmer, I thought it might be be
helpful to give a small tutorial, as one might in beginners class.

The other's that have responded have been correct, but everyone has to
start somewhere.

OK. The section you don't understand has several integer variable,
which are the names of storage locations in the computer's memory.
I'll draw them out to show what they are storing (at the moment they
are empty):

```
  .---.      .---.  .---.  .---.  .---.
  |   |      |   |  |   |  |   |  |   |
  '---'      '---'  '---'  '---'  '---'
numToPrint  current last  lastlast   c
```

Now in Java, new variables are initialised to zero when the program
starts. (This is not true of all languages BTW).

I'll Set the values to those they hold after reading (say) 4 and
positioned at the comment:

`//This is the section I don't really understand`

```
  .---.      .---.  .---.  .---.  .---.
  | 4 |      | 1 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 0 |
  '---'      '---'  '---'  '---'  '---'
numToPrint  current last  lastlast   c
```

Now, moving on a couple of lines, we start the loop:

`for (int c =2; c < numToPrint; c++) {`

We can see that`c < numToPrint` is `true` so we continue:

```
  .---.      .---.  .---.  .---.  .---.
  | 4 |      | 1 |  | 0 |  | 0 |  | 2 |
  '---'      '---'  '---'  '---'  '---'
numToPrint  current last  lastlast   c
```

The next two lines get executed:

`lastlast = last;
last = current;`

```
  .---.      .---.  .---.  .---.  .---.
  | 4 |      | 1 |  | 1 |  | 0 |  | 2 |
  '---'      '---'  '---'  '---'  '---'
numToPrint  current last  lastlast   c
```

Then the next line is:

`current = lastlast + last;`

```
  .---.      .---.  .---.  .---.  .---.
  | 4 |      | 1 |  | 1 |  | 0 |  | 2 |
  '---'      '---'  '---'  '---'  '---'
numToPrint  current last  lastlast   c
```

Then:  `System.out.println(current);`

This outputs "1"

At the bottom of the loop we increment `c` by one:

```
  .---.      .---.  .---.  .---.  .---.
  | 4 |      | 1 |  | 1 |  | 0 |  | 3 |
  '---'      '---'  '---'  '---'  '---'
numToPrint  current last  lastlast   c
```

and then back to the top to compare `c < numToPrint` which is still
 `true`, thus we continue:

The next two lines get executed:

`lastlast = last;
last = current;`

```
  .---.      .---.  .---.  .---.  .---.
  | 4 |      | 1 |  | 1 |  | 1 |  | 3 |
  '---'      '---'  '---'  '---'  '---'
numToPrint  current last  lastlast   c
```

Then the next line is:

`current = lastlast + last;`

```
  .---.      .---.  .---.  .---.  .---.
  | 4 |      | 2 |  | 1 |  | 1 |  | 3 |
  '---'      '---'  '---'  '---'  '---'
numToPrint  current last  lastlast   c
```

Then:  `System.out.println(current);`

This outputs "2"

At the bottom of the loop we increment `c` by one:

```
  .---.      .---.  .---.  .---.  .---.
  | 4 |      | 2 |  | 1 |  | 1 |  | 4 |
  '---'      '---'  '---'  '---'  '---'
numToPrint  current last  lastlast   c
```

and then back to the top to compare `c < numToPrint` which is now
`false`, so the program ends.

Hopefully that helped you understand the code a bit more?
(Courtesy of emacs picture edit mode and a cold beer!)

Answer (score 1):

"How does last variable change from 0 as assigned from above?"
Because you assign the value in current to last with

```
last = current;
```

"How does current variable change from 1? "
Because you assign the sum of lastlast and last to current with

```
current = lastlast + last;
```